# Flutter bottomsheet popup

Tags: flutter

A bottomsheet pops up in my fluutter project. The top of the bottomsheet is an input box. Once opened, there will be a focus, a keyboard will pop up, and a button will pop up below. After clicking the button, a popmenu will pop up. At present, there are two problems. One is that I use the AnimatedPadding keyboard. It feels unnatural to pop up. One is that the bottomsheet and the keyboard will retract after the popmenu pops up after clicking the button, which leads to the wrong position of the popmenu. I have packaged the bottomsheet into a StatefulWidget, but it still doesn’t work.

```dart
    return AnimatedPadding(
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      duration: Duration.zero,
      child: Container(
        padding: widget.padding,
        height: 160,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(16),
            topRight: Radius.circular(16),
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
            currentFocus.unfocus();
            // popmenu
            showPriorityMenu(context, (selectedPriority) {
              setState(() {
                priority = selectedPriority;
                currentFocus.requestFocus();
              });
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

you may await half a second fo the keyboard to hide and then show your pop up menú

```
onPressed: () {
        final currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        currentFocus.unfocus();
        //await for keyboard to hide
        await Future.delayed(Duration(miliseconds: 500));
        // popmenu
        showPriorityMenu(context, (selectedPriority) {
          setState(() {
            priority = selectedPriority;
            currentFocus.requestFocus();
          });
        });
      },
```

but this will make your showPriorityMenu BuildContext context async so i would move it outside the onPressed either to the root of the build method, or if you are using a stateful widget, outside of the build method

Comment: Thank you,I just want to pop up a popmenu on the top of the button in the bottomsheet, and operate in the button onpress. The input box in the bottomsheet is in the focus input state, and the keyboard pops up. After the popmenu pops up, the bottomsheet retracts. Is there no good solution? The API is now Is it supported, or replace popmenu with other components?

Comment: im sorry bro, but i barely understand what you tryna say

Comment: A very simple requirement is that a button in the sheet pops up a popmenu, which will cause the sheet on top of the keyboard to shrink back. I guess the text box in the sheet loses focus, causing the keyboard and sheet to shrink back. I asked gpt and said it was lost Focus, changing it according to what it said didn't work